# How to do a sensitivity test on a function?

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the first value of `beg (x)` for my risk function that it returns me a negative value.

```r
library(FinCal)
risk<-function(inicial,n,q,p,cf,vc,
                 time,sal,num,r,minus,beg){
  qtd<-runif(time,0,q)
  cf<-cf+sal*num
  ll<-p-vc

cashflow<-c(-inicial,
            rep(c(sum(ll*q-(ll*q*minus))-cf),beg),rep(c(sum(ll*q)-cf),n-beg))#

npv(r,cashflow)
}                   
                                            # changes the "beg" argument x 
optim(c(1),function(x){risk(500000,36,1000,20,2000,10,1,2000,3,0.0032,.9,x)},lower=24,upper=9999)$par
```

```
Error in rep(c(sum(ll* q) - cf), n-  : 
  invalid 'times' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In optim(c(1), function(x) { :
  Error in rep(c(sum(ll* q) - cf), beg-  : 
  invalid 'times' argument
```

I don't know if in this case I use the `optim` function or the `min ()` `which ()` function

How do I create a function that changes the values ​​of x and returns me the value of x that my `risk ()` function becomes negative for? I'm trying to create a certain sensitivity test on this function

Comment: Hi, based on what you have defined in the risk function, beg should be between 1 and `n`. because of `n-beg` as `times` argument of `rep`.